# It's possible to calculate amount of data used in Wi-Fi from android app

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

1. I am developing an app in which I need to scans WiFi network and display the list of all connected devices.

I find the solution for device detection from [here](http://bit.ly/QrIwLB).

2. **And I need how much amount of data used from Wi-Fi network?**
   I don't know it's possible or not.

Any one known about my 2nd requirement.

Thanks for your help. Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

**edited:** Can I get this details from my app.

Not installed in user app.

Because this app used for a hotel Wi-Fi. Every customers used hotel Wi-Fi but they don't have app.
Admin of hotel collected amount for usage of data from customer. With help of my app.

Comment: So you want to determine the amount of data consumed by the hotel's guests without installing something on their devices and without installing something on the Wifi access points?

Comment: I doubt this is possible, at least not with standard hardware.

Answer (score 6):

Its possible to know how much data consumed by your device. Android OS provides **[TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)** class which provides you amount of data used by your network.

Try following example.

```
String info = "";

info += "Mobile Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets() + " packets\n");

info += "All Network Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

Log.d("Network","Usage : "+info);
```

**Edit**

As far as i know it is not possible to get information from router that how much data it has consumed. There might be some mechanism to communicate with router. But how to communicate is a big question. Because all router has their security level.

**Suggestion**

If you know about **Tethering & portable hotspot**, you can do one thing. You can create a wi-fi hotspot from your device. You can add **No Security** to allow customer to connect with your wi-fi hotspot.

Your device will be connected with actual wi-fi router and all other customer will connect with your device. So whatever data will be consumed from your device, you can calculate it.

**Note**

wifi hotspot will have limited number of connection.

Comment: But doesn't this only count the data transferred by the device you run this code on?

Comment: This code will count total data transferred/received by your device.

Comment: Yes. The question is get count of all devices.It`s not optimum answer.

Comment: @Chintan Rathod r u know about this requirement.If don`t know put some suggestions.my bounty expires in 22 hours.

Comment: @stacktry I got your problem. You want Wi-Fi router total data usage which all other users also using. Right? This might not be possible if i guess.

Comment: @ranjith isn't answer helped you?

Answer (score 3):

i think you can have the values you want
if the access point/router have them,
so you can request them from the router or request the router's webpage, parse it have your values :D